# Calculate total number of open item at each month in Powerpivot

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I want to find a way to calculate the total amount of open items in each month in powerpivot. My data looks like this...

```
Id    Team    CreatedDate   ClosedDate   
01    AAA     1/30/2014     5/13/2014 
02    BBB     2/9/2014      2/18/2014 
03    CCC     5/10/2014     9/15/2014
```

Result should look like this...

```
Month     Count 
Jan2014   1
Feb2014   2
Mar2014   1
Apr2014   1
May2014   2
Jun2014   1
Jul2014   1
Aug2014   1
Sep2014   1
```

Is any way to do this?

TIA...

Comment: You might get a better response on http://superuser.com/

Comment: Short answer, probably. But we don't have nearly enough information to do this. First, give it a try. Show us your table structure, you PowerPivot relationships, and what you have tried and what hasn't worked. Welcome to SO.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because, the OP has cross-posted on SuperUser: http://superuser.com/questions/901620/calculate-total-number-of-open-item-at-each-month-in-powerpivot